# How to run NET USE to work to map a drive in Cloud Service to an Azure File Services share within webrole

Tags: azure-storage, virtual-directory, smb, azure-cloud-services, cloud-storage

I have created a preview storage account and requested access to the Azure File Services share which allows you to create a share that can be accessed across instances. I have found the following blog post provided by the storage team:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/05/27/persisting-connections-to-microsoft-azure-files.aspx

I have successfully created the share programmatically within my web role start using the following code:

```
public static void CreateCloudShare()
{
    CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SecondaryStorageConnectionString"].ToString());
    CloudFileClient client = account.CreateCloudFileClient();
    CloudFileShare share = client.GetShareReference("scorm");
    share.CreateIfNotExistsAsync().Wait();
}
```

If I log onto the server I can successfully map the drive using the following code from the cmd.exe window:

```
D:\>net use z: \\<storage-account>.file.core.windows.net\scorm /u:<storage-account> <storage-password>
```

I have attempted to include the following code in my Startup.cmd

```
use z: \\<storage-account>.file.core.windows.net\scorm /u:<storage-account> <storage-password>
```

If I log onto the new instance then I can see that there is a z: drive present but says that it is disconnected with the error or password is incorrect error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As also mentioned in the [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/05/27/persisting-connections-to-microsoft-azure-files.aspx), Windows maintains different contexts for each user. Each context can be independently connected to a different set of SMB shares, and each context will have its own drive letter mapping to the shares it is connected to.

Please refer to "User Contexts" and "Web Roles and User Contexts" sections of the same [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/05/27/persisting-connections-to-microsoft-azure-files.aspx). If your goal is to make sure the drive is accessible from your web role, calling [WNetAddConnection2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385413(v=vs.85).aspx) from Global.Application_Start is a good solution.

Comment: where do I add the WNetAddConnection2 code shown? Not sure how this works, I am able to create the drive but it is still showing as disconnected network drive despite being accessible when i log in

Comment: If I run the same net use command from cmd prompt then it works no problem with the drive showing as connected with the name set to the name of the share folder "scorm"

Comment: As mentioned in the blog post, you can call it from Global.Application_Start. The user running startup.cmd, your logon credentials, and the user running your web role are all different from each other. So, a network share mounted from one cannot be used from the other unless "runas" is used.

Comment: I am still very confused and cannot get this to work. Where do the methods MountShare and DLL go? And how do I call this from Application_start. This could have been made clearer in the blog

Comment: This solution doesn't work. I tried "net use" and Win32 api approach, the result is the same. When you type a command in virtual machine, it works. So it doesn't work from the web role.